# Django get model all field after group by

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model;

```py
class Location(models.Model):

    g_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="guard_id")
    corX = models.IntegerField()
    corY = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __int__(self):
        return self.map_id
```

ı want to get the newest record per foreign key using this query;

```
query = Location.objects.values('g_id').annotate(timestamp=Max('date'))
```

This my query result.

```
<QuerySet [{'g_id': 1, 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 29, 8, 57, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'g_id': 2, 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 29, 8, 55, 50, tzinfo=<UTC>)}]>
```

How to get corX, corY values with groupping data?

Comment: Am I right in assuming you want the newest `corX` and `corY` per `g_id`?

Comment: Yes @AKX ı want to get this data.

Comment: @uyarc What database do you use?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I use postgresql database

Comment: You'll then need a window function, most likely. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`distinct` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) on the field `g_id` while ordering with `-date` to get only one entry for each `g_id` with `date` being maximum:

```py
query = Location.objects.order_by('g_id', '-date').distinct('g_id')
```

> **Note**: This will only work on **PostgreSQL** as you can specify the fields in the distinct call only for **PostgreSQL**.

Comment: Thanks @Abdul Aziz Barkat.